# Analytic integration of tricky bivariate Gaussian PDF

Tags: integration

I have this somewhat complicated expression in terms of the following 8 variables (note: actually, $X$ and $Y$ are variables, and $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are longer expressions as a funtion two other variables, say $Z$ and $T$, which I need to keep intact) of the form:

$F(X,Y,a,b,c,d,e,f)=aXYe^{bX+cY+dXY+eX^2+fY^2}$

And I need to perform the double integral over the two dimensions X and Y:

$G(a,b,c,d,e,f)=\int\limits^1_0\int\limits^\infty_0 F(X,Y,a,b,c,d,e,f) dYdX$

where the parameters $a, b, c, d, e$, and $f$ all contain other variables which I need to keep intact. Because of this, numerical integration won't quite work. Ultimately I need to find the analytical form of $G(a,b,c,d,e,f)$, even though it'll be quite complicated.

This is what I've found so far. On Mathematica, I was able to complete the $dY$ integral from $0$ to $\infty$. This returned a somewhat complicated 3-term expression. I was able to easily integrate the first two terms over $dX$ and return expressions in terms of $a,b,c,d,e,f$. However, the third term has the following form:

$\int\limits^1_0 j X(1+kX) \text{Erf} \lbrack m+nX \rbrack e^{oX+pX^2} dX$

Where Erf[] is the error function, and $j,k,m,n,o,p$ are new parameters in terms of $a,b,c,d,e,f$. 
So ultimately, it boils down to that integral, which I have no idea how to solve! Does anyone have any ideas or approximation/simplifications which could help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the lowercase $x^2$ in  your definition of $F$ actually be $X^2$? Then this would amount to solving a Gaussian integral

Comment: @janosch oops, my bad - you're right that it should be $X^2$. And yeah, but the integration limits make it tricky. This would be very simple if they were from -infinity..infinity